# Basis of Column Space of matrix that is in Row Reduced Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm considerably new to proving things(and to Linear Algebra too).So, I hope someone would help me with this.

While proving **Row Rank of Matrix = Column Rank of Matrix**

Proof used the point that

> For a Row Reduced Echelon Matrix, Basis of Column Space is just set of
>   columns that contain leading non-zero entries.

Can someone provide a proof of this (Hints would more be appreciated)?

Comment: If you mean the column space of the rref and not the original matrix, this should be pretty obvious. Each such column has a different single nonzero entry that corresponds to a nonzero row of the rref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the proof you are looking for take a look to [Prove that pivot columns of row reduced form of any matrix forms a basis in column space of that row reduced matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490979/prove-that-pivot-columns-of-row-reduced-form-of-any-matrix-forms-a-basis-in-colu) for the simpler case and here for the other [Pivot columns of A are a basis for Col(A)](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/handouts/col-basis.pdf).

For the proof of this fundamental result and property of matrices you can take a look here [Proofs that column rank = row rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

For the intuition behind take a look here [intuitive explanation why the row rank is equal to the column rank for a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332908/505767).

Comment: my question is not about proof of column rank=row rank.It's about basis of column space when a matrix is in row reduced echelon form.

Comment: @viru Yes sorry but at first I didn't uderstand what you were looking for, I hope the given reference are useful to clarify the point. Bye

Comment: Thanks, that pdf has answer to exactly what I was looking for.Besides it's simpler too :).